# Ask for location permission multiple times flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, geolocation

My code gets the user location without errors. Problems appear when the user deny the access for the location and later he wants to allow it.
I don't know how to handle the process.

These are the steps :

- initState to ask location -> If the user allow the access everything is fine.
- initState -> users deny access.
  If user deny the access I'm not able to ask for it again so I will never have the position from the user.
  I need to understand how to handle the refuse phase.
  This is the code :

  ```
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
  import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

  class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  static Future<void> show(
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Maps(),
        fullscreenDialog: true,
      ),
    );
    }
  @override
  _MapsState createState() => _MapsState();
  }

  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
  return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator();

  String _location;
  String _addressLine;
  bool done = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getCurrentLocation();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: _navBar(),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                done == false
                    ? textOnScreen("Need to get the position")
                    : textOnScreen("val 1: $_location, val 2: $_addressLine"),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Get location"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      done = false;
                      _getCurrentLocation();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget textOnScreen(String text) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: null,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  Widget _navBar() {
    return CupertinoNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      middle: Text(
        'Get position',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getLocation(Position position) async {
    debugPrint('location: ${position.latitude}');
    final coordinates = new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    List<Address> addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    Address first = addresses.first;
    _location = "${first.featureName}";
    _addressLine = " ${first.addressLine}";
    setState(() {
      done = true;
    });
  }

  void _getCurrentLocation() {
    // if (await )
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      _getLocation(position);
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: you only need to call your _getCurrentLocation() location  in your initState() method

Comment: I'll edit with the entire code

Comment: You need to detect the `.denied` authorisation state and show some sort of alert or message that prompts the user to go into settings and change the permission. There is no way to get ios to ask again.

Comment: Ooooh ok I got you thanks mate!